# ¿Como mostrar un alerta al seleccionar una opcion especifica de un html-select> option creado con un 'new' desde JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html5, html-select, alert

Tengo el siguiente JS y HTML, que, al seleccionar una opcion del primer select, cambia las opciones del segundo select. La intencion es, al seleccionar una opcion de este segundo select (que se modifica según la seleccion del primero) mostrar un alerta en uno especifico.

Puse, para el ejemplo, en el primer select, la opcion "combinaciones" y al seleccionarla, en el segundo select, esta la opcion "Alerta", cuando se seleccione "alerta" deberia mostrar un Alert, sin importar el mensaje. 
Estoy teniendo problemas para ejecutar el alert en ese punto especificamente (es decir, al seleccionar la opcion "alerta"), al momento solo pude ejecutar el alert solo al cargar la pagina.

Si me pueden iluminar, les agradezco mucho. Voy a estar atento a los comentarios y sugerencias.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script language="JavaScript">
    function cambiar() {
      var index = document.forms.RA.Clasificaciones.selectedIndex;

      RA.Subclasificaciones.length = 0;

      if (index == 1) fun1();
      if (index == 2) fun2();
      if (index == 3) fun3();
    }

    function fun1() {
      opcion0 = new Option("-Seleccione-", "Seleccione una Subclasificacion", "defauldSelected");
      opcion1 = new Option("Texto", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur");
      opcion2 = new Option("Texto2", "Adipisicing elit Asperiores cumque distinctio ab ea vel.");
      opcion3 = new Option("Texto3", "Lorem ipsum lorem");

      document.forms.RA.Subclasificaciones.options[0] = opcion0;
      document.forms.RA.Subclasificaciones.options[1] = opcion1;
      document.forms.RA.Subclasificaciones.options[2] = opcion2;
      document.forms.RA.Subclasificaciones.options[3] = opcion3;
    }

    function fun2() {
      opcion0 = new Option("-Seleccione-", "Seleccione una Subclasificacion", "defauldSelected");
      opcion1 = new Option("Numeros", "123");
      opcion2 = new Option("Numeros2", "456");
      opcion3 = new Option("Numeros3", "789");

      document.forms.RA.Subclasificaciones.options[0] = opcion0;
      document.forms.RA.Subclasificaciones.options[1] = opcion1;
      document.forms.RA.Subclasificaciones.options[2] = opcion2;
      document.forms.RA.Subclasificaciones.options[3] = opcion3;
    }

    function fun3() {
      opcion0 = new Option("-Seleccione-", "Seleccione una Subclasificacion", "defauldSelected");
      opcion1 = new Option(" Letras y numeros ", " 123ABC");
      opcion2 = new Option(" Alerta", " Acompañando este texto se debe mostrar un alerta");
      opcion3 = new Option(" Letras y numeros2 ", " 098ZYX");

      document.forms.RA.Subclasificaciones.options[0] = opcion0;
      document.forms.RA.Subclasificaciones.options[1] = opcion1;
      document.forms.RA.Subclasificaciones.options[2] = opcion2;
      document.forms.RA.Subclasificaciones.options[3] = opcion3;
    }

    var mostrarValor = function(x) {
      document.getElementById('subclasificacion').value = x;
    }

    var mostrarValor2 = function(x) {
      document.getElementById('subclasificacion2').value = x;
    }
  </script>


</head>

<body>

  <form action="" method="post" name="RA">
    <select name="Clasificaciones" onchange="cambiar()">
      <option value="0">-Seleccione-</option>
      <option value="1">Lorem</option>
      <option value="2">Numerologia</option>
      <option value="3">Combinaciones</option>
    </select>

    <select name="Subclasificaciones" onchange="mostrarValor(this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML); mostrarValor2(this.value);">
      <option value="0">-Seleccione-</option>
    </select>

    <br>
  </form>
  <form>
    <p>Valor Seleccionado: </p>
    <textarea cols="60" rows="2" name="subclasificacion" id="subclasificacion" readonly> -Seleccione una Clasificacion y una Subclasificacion- </textarea>
    <p>
      <p>Valor mostrado:</p>
      <textarea cols="60" rows="6" input type="text" name="subclasificacion2" id="subclasificacion2"></textarea>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Buenas, tu problema es que no sabes por donde poner ese `alert()` (ya que no lo has puesto por ninguna parte). Ya que `new option()` no admite atributos (como `onclick`) tendrás que ponerlo en la funcción `mostrarValor()` comparando si `x=="Alerta".trim()`. `trim()` quita los espacios sobrantes. Si lo quieres hacer con el atributo `onclick` tendrás que utilizar `document.createElement`

Comment: Gracias, al ser autodidacta, me estaba volviendo loco al intentar implementar onClick(), desconocía que no admitía el atributo. Voy a implementar el if y voy a replicar el código con document.createElement para probar también como funciona. 
Sumaste el método de recorte que me va a ser muy útil en las implementaciones que estoy haciendo. 

Nuevamente, muchas gracias, es la respuesta que esperaba.